# simplify $\sqrt[3]{x \sqrt[3]{ x \sqrt[3]{x ...}} }$ -- if $x$ is negative?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, recreational-mathematics

Was given this recreational problem: simplify $$\sqrt[3]{x \sqrt[3]{ x \sqrt[3]{x ...}} }$$

The solution isn't hard. Let $y = \sqrt[3]{x \sqrt[3]{ x \sqrt[3]{x ...}} }$, then $y^3 = xy$, $y=\sqrt{x}$

The problem didn't specify, but if $x$ is negative, would this work?

Comment: $y^2-x=0$ is a parabola that is defined for $x\geq0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tagged your question with "complex analysis" and "complex numbers".  In this context, however, the function $x \mapsto \sqrt[3]{x}$ needs to be defined more clearly.

For instance, if we define $$\sqrt[3]{re^{\theta i}} = \sqrt[3]{r}\cdot e^{\theta i / 3} \\ \sqrt{re^{\theta i}} = \sqrt{r}\cdot e^{\theta i / 2}$$ for $r \geq 0$ and $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$, then you *can* show $$\sqrt[3]{x \sqrt[3]{ x \sqrt[3]{x ...}} } = \sqrt{x}$$
for any $x \in \mathbb{C}.$  This works both as a fixed point of the function $y \mapsto \sqrt[3]{xy}$ and as a limit of the sequence $x_0 = \sqrt[3]{x}$ and $x_{n+1} = \sqrt[3]{xx_n}$.

Answer (score 3):

Note if $x$ is real, with $x \lt 0$, then you have

$$\sqrt[3]{x} \lt 0 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt[3]{x}} \gt 0 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

$$\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt[3]{x}}} \lt 0 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

I trust you see the issue that occurs as you keep expanding the expression to have more cube roots in it.

Comment: In other words, it does not approach a limit.

Comment: A priori, this could allow it to approach a limit of 0, but it doesn't do that because the absolute value of the outputs approach $\sqrt{|x|}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt[3]{x\dots}}}$

So,

$y=\sqrt[3]{xy}$

Now raise both side to the power $3$, we get:

$y^3=xy$

Now, $y\ne0$ because $x$ is negative as mentioned in the problem statement, we can divide both sides by $y$, we get:

$y^2=x$

However $y^2=x$ has no real solution since $x$ is negative. Hence the given expression does not have a closed form. [THIS IS THE REQUIRED ANSWER].

---

When $x$ is positive, then the equation $y^2=x$ reduces to $y=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: I think by "does not have a closed form" you meant "is undefined" or similar. The claim it does not have a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) would allow it to still be defined, just without a tidy way to write it.

Comment: @MarkS. First of all, thanks for commenting on those terms. The problem is that my English is poor, I am Arabic. Second, the given expression is defined for all $x$ (for +ve and -ve x's), but just without a tidy way to write it for -ve x.

Comment: Based on [John's observation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3621304/26369) about the signs and the fact that the absolute value output approaches the square root of the absolute value of the input, I would argue it is not defined for negative values of $x$, without redefining the cube root in a non-standard way as in [Brian's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3621327/26369).